# Distributing aggregated zone data to smaller polygons within these zones, weighted by a field value

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro

I'm trying to find a hack to better represent the spatial distribution of population and employment density with aggregated zone level data. I'm using ArcGIS Pro (but can use ArcGIS Desktop).

My inputs:

- traffic zone (TAZ) polygon shapefile with existing and projected future population/employment
- building polygons with heights. I have derived the building volume from this

I would like to distribute the aggregated totals in the traffic zone file to the building polygons, weighted by their volume. I'm struggling to find a way to do this. Anyone have any ideas or resources they can point me to?

Comment: The technique is called Daisymetric mapping. There are several different approaches with slightly different effects https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1559/152304001782173727

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try:

**1)** joining the TAZ attributes to the polygons file, probably by location, the options depending on your dataset. ([In ArcGIS Pro](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/tables/spatial-joins-by-feature-type.htm))

**2)** Get the sum of building volumes for each TAZ, maybe with summary statistics. ([In ArcGIS Pro](https://pro.arcgis.com/de/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/summary-statistics.htm))

**3)** Join the "total building volume per TAZ" attribute to your building dataset, probably by TAZ ID. ([In ArcGIS Pro](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/join-field.htm))

**4)** Calculate a new field: weight. This would be the building's volume divided by the total volume of the TAZ (attribute joined in point 2 and 3). ([In ArcGIS Pro](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-field.htm))

**5)** Calculate a new field: weighted X. Multiply your weight (obtained in point 4) and your attribute X of interest (existing and projected future population/employment). ([In ArcGIS Pro](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-field.htm))